# Referencing CMSIS registers in C++ without using #define

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, reinterpret-cast, cmsis

We are using Atmel's ASF (3.48) with Studio 7 (on an ATSAM4E series MCU), with the arm-gnu-toolchain 9-2020-q2-update. The team has recently decided to write more higher interface layers with C++, while still using the CMSIS and ASF drivers in C as they are. With that in mind, I am trying to replace the following in my interface file:

`#define MY_DEBUG_UART    UART0`

with

`constexpr Uart *MY_DEBUG_UART = UART0;`

Now, `UART0` is defined in the relevant CMSIS/SAM4E file as

`#define UART0      ((Uart   *)0x400E0600U) /**< \brief (UART0     ) Base Address */`

So upon building, an error is returned with this UART0 #define.

Error       reinterpret_cast from integer to pointer

I *think* I see why. But the examples I have seen seem to involve setting up a register class. I don't want to duplicate things and would like to use the drivers provided, have the readability of #defines without its accompanying issues, and utilise the C++ advantages. What's the cleanest way to achieve this please?

Comment: So.. just remove `constexpr` and replace with `static Uart * const`.

Comment: Thanks. I have ended up with static const Uart* const MY_DEBUG_UART = UART0. My thinking is UART0  being a register address should be treated as a constant, and I don't want the pointer to change either.